# Whitespace reading with external file

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with reading from an external file that has whitespace when I want to read a string.

This is the external file format:

```
5
SD Mines
77 40
Northern State
80 64
BYU
77 65
Creighton
81 88
Sam Houston State
60 49
```

This is the code that I have that is reading the file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    inputFile >> b[i].visitTeam >> b[i].homeScore >> b[i].visitScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream::oprator>>()` functions stop reading when they encounter white space. You can use `std::getline()` to read the entire line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    std::getline(inputFIle, b[i].visitTeam);
    inputFile >> b[i].homeScore >> b[i].visitScore;

    // Now, make sure you skip everything in the line.
    // Otherwise, the next call to getline() will return an
    // empty string.
    inputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: The >> were not picking up my homescores but the getline was getting my team right. I am using inputFile.ignore(); before my >> operoters and still getting it wrong but everything else is right.

Comment: Here is what I have and what I am getting [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/846430adaa96d0e064ee) The only thing wrong is the Home Team scores.

Comment: That is caused by the call to `inputFile.ignore()` after the call to `getline()`. You don't need the first two calls to `ignore()`. You only need the last one.